# Lowest dimensional faithful representation of a finite group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, linear-transformations

How does one compute the lowest dimensional faithful representation of a finite group?

This question originated in the context of given a finite group $G$: trying to find the lowest dimensional shape whose rotational/reflection symmetries form $G$. (Formally stated as finding the lowest dimensional faithful representation of $G$ into the orthogonal group $O(n)$.)

Now just listing out examples is hard, because even in just $\mathbb{R}^2$ outside of the symmetries of simple polygons we see things like $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 $ crop up, yet it appears that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ doesn't have any obvious two dimensional representations. Grouppropswiki doesn't even have a single representation for it at all.

So I thought it was wise before I tackle the orthogonal group question I should know how to just, in general, find a low dimensional faithful representation. Some trivialities are that the dimension for a group $G$ will be less than or equal to the smallest $j$ such that $G \subset S_j$ since each symmetric group can be realized as the symmetries of a $j$-dimensional simplex space due to Burnside.

But this doesn't say much because even something like $\mathbb{D}_{\text{Graham's Number}}$ can be realized in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (and we still are dealing with isometries here, what about represenatations that transcend that!?)

Comment: Are you talking about complex representations, or representations over an arbitrary field? For complex representations, the smallest dimension of a faithful representation of a finite abelian group with minimal generating set of size $d$ is $d$. But $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ has a faithful $2$-dimensional representation over the finite field of order $8$. In general, this is a difficult problem - even finding the smallest degree faithful permutation representation can be difficult.

Comment: I'm focusing on real representations. Does that make matters worse?

Comment: It's a difficult problem in general over any field. For an abelian group with invariant factor decomposition $C_{k_1} \times \cdots C_{k_r} \times C_2^s$ with each $k_i > 2$, I think the smallest dimension of a real faithful representation is $2r+s$. It is certainly $s$ for $C_2^s$.

Comment: Is there a list of these smallest dimensions somewhere for small groups? @DerekHolt

Comment: For future visitors: some research developments since this question was asked https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351938/bounds-on-the-lowest-dimension-of-a-faithful-representation-of-a-finite-group/382301 as well it is interesting to ask even whether there are small irreducible representations, as discussed here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400864/is-operatornamepsl2-q-the-most-quasirandom-group/400871#400871 Finally, note that $j$ in the question statement is called the minimal degree in group theory; computing is still open in many cases.