# Is it possible to realize any finite group as a subgroup of a semisimple Lie group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups

This question seems rather trivial after seeing the answers. So now I would also like to know what's the lowest dimension of the Lie group given the rank or the order of the finite group? For example, for dihedral groups, no matter how large the order is, we only need a one dimensional Lie group.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hint:  Can you realize a symmetric group inside a Lie group?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688173/lowest-dimensional-faithful-representation-of-a-finite-group

Answer (score 4):

By Cayley, every finite group is a subgroup of $S_n\subseteq GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. Here $S_n$ is represented by permutation matrices. This has been proved at this question in detail:

[Show that any finite group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ for some $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400420/show-that-any-finite-group-g-is-isomorphic-to-a-subgroup-of-gl-n-mathbbr)

Comment: Sorry that the original question is kind of trivial. I have modified it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also realize $S_n$ inside $SL(n+1, \mathbb{R})$ (indeed inside $SO(n+1, \mathbb{R})$ by the map
$$\sigma\mapsto (P_{\sigma}, \epsilon(\sigma) )$$